# creating structs or cell array in an efficient way when reading a txt file

Tags: matlab, parsing, file-io, struct, cell-array

I have a file whose format is

```
17  8   miller  234.7

51  14  smith   256.3
```

I would like to read the file in such a way that each line will be a struct or a cell array (so that I can sort according to each field)

I tried using `textread()`:

```
[buildngNumber,floorNumber,familyName,familyEarnings] = textread('data.txt','%d %d %s %f ');
```

but i get 4 array/cell arrays :

```
buildngNumber =

    17
    51


floorNumber =

     8
    14


familyName = 

    'miller'
    'smith'


familyEarnings =

  234.7000
  256.3000
```

and I want something like this `{17 8   miller  234.7}`, `{51   14  smith   256.3}` or maybe to put each line in a struct. Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The function you are probably looking for is [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html). 
In order to use it, you have to specify the format of your data. 
In your case that would be two integers, followed by a string and a float value:

```
formatSpec = '%d %d %s %f';
```

You find details on how to build the format string on the help page linked above, in the section *Input Arguments*.

With that you can read the whole file into a cell array:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','r');
C = textscan(fid,formatSpec);
fclose(fid);
```

which will create the cell array

```
C = 
[2x1 int32]    [2x1 int32]    {2x1 cell}    [2x1 double]
```

You can then access e.g. the building numbers by `C{:,1}` or e.g. all info on the first family by `C{1,:}`.

Comment: can I sort the families in the cell array according to other families?i.e is ther anyway to sort the first family and then if the number at index i is now index j the same would happen in the other families?